# "Seems to [...]": how to express tha indirect object?

Tags: translation, grammar

I [am planning to translate all of Sappho to Chinese](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/07/chinese-poetic-sappho.html?m=1). I wanted to start from Sappho Campbell 31 / Edmonds 2 (which is fragment theta there as well as [here](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/07/all-of-sappho.html?m=1), theta being the Greek way of writing 9), and that requires me to translate "that man seems to me". As far as "that man seems", I can get:

> 那个人看起来 | Nà ge rén kànqǐlái,

or with `仿佛 | fǎngfú` or even `显得 | xiânde` (or other similar verbs like `似乎 | sìhu`). But "to me"? The only thing I could think of was:

> 我觉得那个人看起来 | Wô juéde nà ge rén kànqîlái,

but for some reason I don't like this. So how do I translate that indirect object into Chinese?

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I put the full translation in the post just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "**那个人看起来**"(that man seems) is perfectly fine
- You can omit "看起来"  in "我觉得那个人看起来" and just write "**我觉得那个人**"

There are other choices:

- 對我來說，那個人 ( to me, that man)
- 在我看來，那個人 ( from my point of view, that man)
- 我看那個人 ( I see that man/ that man, to me)

Comment: Hey Tang, do you not believe in upvoting questions, only answering them?

Comment: Could I say 在我的看来? Basically, I'm thinking of how to continue the translation of the poem I mention in the post, and it goes on with a relative clause, so I'd start with `在我的看来，那个正在你 ／ 的旁边坐下，听你来说话 ／ 说得很甜蜜 的人看起来 ／ 就像上帝一样的。`, which would be the whole first stanza, and a bit of the second one. Though thinking on it, that huge relative clause had probably better be avoided… but anyways, is 在我的看来 OK?

Comment: "Could I say 在我的看来?" -- no, you can't .  我 is the subject,  看 is the verb. '的' has no role between them. The correct structure: "在我看来, 那个正在你旁边坐下，听你来说话说得很甜蜜的人, 看起来就像上帝一样的。"

Comment: Actually, here is another translation: `在我看来，来坐在你／ 旁边而听 到你说话 ／ 说得甜蜜， 甜蜜得笑， ／ 让人仿佛跟上帝／ 一样。`, which keeps the sentence overflowing into the second stanza. What do you think? English «Equal to the gods he seems to me, / That man who in front of you / Sits, and, near you, to you sweetly speaking / Listens, / And [sees you] lovably smiling».

Comment: OK, I'll just go with my alternate translation then.

Comment: @Stumpy Joe Pete.  Up voting the questions I answer myself,  seems to be too self-serving. For that same reason, I never down vote any answer if I myself have answered the same question too.

Comment: I disagree (at least on the first one); it helps out the questioner, and it _really_ helps out the questioner if they're relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

English «Equal to the gods he seems to me, / That man who in front of you / Sits, and, near you, to you sweetly speaking / Listens, / And [sees you] lovably smiling».

Chinese <那个男人--我心中的男神，他就站在你的眼前，然后慢慢靠近你，坐在你的身边说着甜言蜜语，聆听你的倾诉，看着你可爱迷人的微笑>

I try to make this translation for you. This is my understanding of the stanza. You can make reference.